# Slowly varying function without limit at infinity

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, slowly-varying-functions

A function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is *slowly varying at infinity* if for any $t>0$
$$
\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{f(xt)}{f(x)}=1.
$$
Is there a **bounded** function slowly varying at infinity whose limit as $x \to +\infty$ does not exist?

Comment: Does this include functions whose limit as $x \to +\infty$ is $\pm \infty$?

Comment: No. In that case the limit is not finite, but it exists. I am looking for a function which behaves "wildly" (i.e. $ \sin(x)$) at $\infty$. But thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 7):

How about $f(x)=2+\sin \ln \ln x$? Note that the difference between $\ln\ln(xt)$ and $\ln x$ tends to $0$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: @MaartenHilferink I solemnly swear I can see no such answer of yours.

Comment: I don't know how to prove the limit of the definition of slowly variation. But the idea of the $\log(\log(\cdot))$ applies to the the function $(-1)^{[\log\log(x)]}$, where $[ \cdot ]$ is the integer part.

Comment: @Iddqd The function (-1)^thing has slow variation? How?